# Get td class of clicked tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the class of td from clicked tr?

I've this structure:

```
<tr role="row" data-id="1" class="odd parent">
   <td class="sorting_1">test</td>
   <td>foo</td>
   <td>3223232</td>
</tr>
```

I wrote this code:

```
$('#datatable > tbody > tr').click(function()
```

what I want to do is prevent to handle the code above if the user click on the `td` with class `sorting_1`. Each tr have a td with this class, so I need to check if the user have clicked on this td class, and prevent the code execution.

**UPDATE**

The code provided by @T.J. Crowder working good but, when I click on the `<td>`that have this class I cannot continue the code, that's correct. But I need to check if the td also contains `::before`, infact this will added when the html does not have sufficient space (responsive), the right structure in this case is:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd parent" data-id="1">
    <td class="sorting_1">test</td>
       ::before
       "test"
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>3223232</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by telling the handler to ignore `td`s with that class:

```
$('#datatable > tbody > tr').on("click", "td:not(.sorting_1)", function(e) (
// -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
});
```

(This covers both of the scenarios below, direct clicks as well as clicks on descendants of the `td`.)

---

Alternately, you can do that by examining the `target` property on the event object your handler receives:

```
$('#datatable > tbody > tr').click(function(e) (
    // -------------------------------------^
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("sorting_1")) {
        // Don't do it
        return;
    }
});
```

If the `td` may have other elements inside it (`span`, `em`, etc.), you can use `closest` to find out:

```
$('#datatable > tbody > tr').click(function(e) (
    // -------------------------------------^
    if ($(e.target).closest(".sorting_1").length) {
        // Don't do it
        return;
    }
});
```

---

Re your additional question:

> is possible check also if the td have `:before`? 'cause the `:before` is added when there is no space available to fit the html content (responsive). So your code working, but if I click on the td that have the class and there is no `:before` I cannot see the content to be displayed. Is possible check :before existence on this td?

You can get that from `getComputedStyle` on modern browsers:

```js
console.log(
  getComputedStyle($("#target")[0], "::before").content
);
```

```css
#target::before {
  content: 'Life, the Universe, and Everything? '
}
```

```html
<div id="target">42</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I don't think you can get it on older browsers that don't support `getComputedStyle`. Also, test on your target browsers to decide between `:before` (the old pseudo-class) and `::before` (its newer name).

Comment: Yes, this seems working (solution 1) I doesn't tried the second solution. Thanks for this :)

Comment: only a question: is possible check also if the td have `:before`? 'cause the `:before` is added when there is no space available to fit the html content (responsive). So your code working, but if I click on the td that have the class and there is no `:before` I cannot see the content to be displayed. Is possible check `:before` existence on this td?

Comment: @AgainMe: That's an entirely separate question, but I've added a note to the end of the above.